# How to show a popup before submitting the information

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Asp.Net/C# , I am having a requirement wherein I want to display a confirm before submission of data , if user clicks OK button , then proceed , or else cancel the submission.I know javascript confirm box does this , but in my case I need to show my own popup , Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this.I would not want to use any plugin here.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: refer http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=117405

Answer (score 1):

you can create as follow:

```
function createPopup() {
    //Get the data from the form fields
    var background = document.custom.back.value;
    var title = document.custom.title.value;
    var text = document.custom.text.value;

    //Now create the HTML code that is required to make the popup
    var content = "<html><head><title>"+title+"</title></head>\
<body bgcolor='"+background+"'><h1>"+title+"</h1>"+text+"<br />\
<a href='javascript:window.close()'>Close the popup</a></body></html>";

    //Create the popup
    var popup = window.open("","window","resizeable,width=400,height=300");
    popup.document.write(content); //Write content into it.
    pops.document.close();
}
```

the logic should like as follow: i have not executed and tested just see the logic ignore minore mistakes if any.. also set the layout, border look like the confirmation window.

```
  function popup() {
    alert('popup called');

    //Now create the HTML code that is required to make the popup
    var content = "<html><head><title>ConfirmBox</title></head><body >Do you want to continue ? <br />
    <input type='button' value='ok' onclick='return true'/>
    <input type='button' value='cancel' onclick='return false'/>    <a href='javascript:window.close()'>Close the popup</a></body></html>";

    //Create the popup
    var popup = window.open("","window","resizeable,width=400,height=300");
    popup.document.write(content); //Write content into it.
    pops.document.close();
}
```

refer http://www.openjs.com/tutorials/advanced_tutorial/popup.php

Comment: This won't act as a confirm window...;)

Comment: i have just shown the way in the window he can return false and true depending the click of the buttons created in its body..

Comment: I know, but I think that's exactly the part he's having troubles with. Opening a window shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @HemantMetalia thanks for the help , my popup is already created , I just want a way where ok button will return true and cancel will return false .

Comment: @walther , you are correct , my popup is ready I just want my function to reutn true or false based on the button clicked.